# Does WebView's loadUrl method run on UI thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, webview

I am wondering how does webview load a particular URL. Does it create a new thread or load the URL in the same thread i.e. UI thread? The reason I am asking this is I am facing some weird wakeup lock issue when I launch an Activity from current Activity (in current Activity's onCreate method) which creates a WebView in it's onCreate method and loads a URL using loadUrl method. So when I am done  with this activity and go back to the Activity which launched this is restarted because wakeup lock time was expired.
I googled it and found out that if onCreate method of an Activity takes too long then this type of issue might occur. Have any of you faced this kind of issue involving a WebView? Any kind of help would be really appreciated.
 Here is sample code.

```
Activity A:
class ActivityA {
  onCreate(){
    initializeSomething();
    registerSomeEvents();
    startSomething();
  }
  onSomeListener(){
    if(someFlag) {
      startActivity(ActivityB);
      //this will pause the current activity i.e. ActivityA
    }
  }
}
Activity B:
class ActivityB(){
  onCreate() {
    if(someFlag){ //someFlag is coming in intent
     helper = createHelperX();
    } else {
     helper = createHelperY();
    }
    helper.pleaseHelp(); //this does the rest of thing using activity instance
}
```

HelperX:

class HelperX(){
  createHelper() {
    //setup layout views etc, no WebView here
    //and wait for user interaction
    //register some events
  }
  onSomeEvent(){
    if(someOtherFlag) {
      startActivityForResult(ActivityB); //and pass some flag, now this flag will trigger HelperY
  }
}

HelperY:
class HelperY(){
  createHelper() {
    //setup views etc , this contains a WebView and calls loadURL.
  }
}

Comment: Hi, I have used WebViews (and loadUrl) in onCreate and never faced any issue (even did XML parsing in the same onCreate). What else are you doing in your onCreate? Are you launching the activity as a peer or as a child activity?

Comment: so startActivityForResult creates a child activity? if it does then yes I am launching a child activity.

Comment: I have added somewhat sample code.

Comment: This is a little generic. Could you paste more specific code.

Comment: Hi, Found out the problem, which was happening. The main activity code was doing some bad stuff when new activity was being launched. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loadUrl method in WebView uses the Handler mechanism i.e it will run in UI thread. You should stop the data loading by calling webView.stopLoading() when the activity is paused/stopped.

Comment: Could this be why sometimes the webview seems to crash my app with no error message, when calling the loadUrl from another class?

Comment: how do u make it run on a different thread ten because when you put it inside its own thread it fails saying it cannot run on a different thread